# how to define an array as argument in class constructor?

Tags: java, arrays, arguments

I want to ask what is the proper way to define an array as argument in class constructor ?

for example

```
public class example {
    int x;
    int y;
    String [] x = new Array [5];

    public example(int x, int y, String [] x){
    etc etc etc.
```

Is `String [] x` is written right ? because netbeans is giving an error however i change it.

Comment: ARe you sure it's giving you error at that location. It seems like you would get the error a couple of line behind.

Comment: FIXED. mistakenly putted "Array" .

Comment: There were a bunch of typographical mistake in your question which were all edited away. I rolled it back so that the answers make sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the proper way, but you have repeated `x` variable name. Change second `x` to `z` for example.

Comment: oh sorry lol, was just doing a quick example.
so i was doing it right .. it's weird that netbeans kept underlining it with red

Answer (score 0):

You can define the array as such:

```
 String[] x = new String[5];
```

edit: and make sure you don't repeat variable names so change x to something else as you have defined x as an int already.

Answer (score 0):

```
String [] x = new Array [5];
```

should be

```
String [] x = new String[5];
```

And your variable `x` is a duplicate. You should change that.

Also, class names start with an upper case letter by convention.

You should also work on your formatting / indent for easier readable code.